# Simple echo of github.event fails in Github Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I just want to print out the `github.event` context in a GitHub Actions step, so I am doing the following

```yaml
      - name: check context
        shell: bash
        run: echo ${{ toJSON(github.event) }}
```

However this fails as follows:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/hd73999-5309-44cf-9218-9e2e3805d525.sh: line 2: after:: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

(although the `github.event` **DOES** get printed before the error.

Why is that?

I am using the `toJSON` function because if I don't all that gets printed is:

```
Run echo Object
Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Updated 10/23

A better method avoid escaping issues is to dump the context to an environment variable and then just echo that out in bash.

```
name: Context testing
on: push

jobs:
  dump_contexts_to_log:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```

You need to add quotes around the expression so it doesn't evaluate it as JS.

From: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log

```yaml
name: Context testing
on: push

jobs:
  dump_contexts_to_log:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        id: github_context_step
        run: echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}'
```

Comment: quoting alone doesn't work if the contents of github contains a quote. https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1656#issuecomment-1030077729

Comment: @DrewMichel updated to a better method